# Case insensitive git merge

Tags: git, merge

I have to merge 2 branches of the fortran code I am working on. Fortran being case insensitive, some time ago, there was no policy about the case of our lines of code (the vast majority were uppercase, but some were lowercase). And at a given time, we chose to pass everything to lowercase. Now before every commit, we pass a script on the whole source code that pass the code to lowercase.

My problem is that I have to merge 2 branches whose common ancestor dates back to a time when the case was not controlled. So when merging, almost every file that differs get a conflict due to the case mismatch (which is a "false" conflict to me).

Is it possible (I hope so...) and how to make an insensitive git merge? If it is not possible, is it possible to call our lowercase script on the common ancestor during the merge process?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ElpieKay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38049246/1256452) is probably sufficient, and I would probably try it first, especially since it should reduce future headaches as well, and is not as fiddly as clean and smudge filters.

If you continue to have trouble with it, though, note that Git's recursive merge [offers a `renormalize` strategy-option](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html):<sup>1</sup>

> `renormalize`
>          This runs a virtual check-out and check-in of all three stages
>   of a file when resolving a three-way merge. This option is
>   meant to be used when merging branches with different clean
>   filters or end-of-line normalization rules. See "Merging
>   branches with differing checkin/checkout attributes" in
>   [gitattributes(5)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) for details.

You can then set up a "clean" filter to convert to lowercase.  Git will use the filter defined in the `HEAD` commit, on all three stages.  If you've already lower-cased in the current (`--ours`) and other (`--thiers`) commits, this will simply lower-case the base version.

Note that this "clean" filter will continue to be applied to files `git add`-ed, until you take away the `.gitattributes`.  That may be a desired feature. :-)

---

<sup>1</sup>As [the `gitattributes` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) notes, there is a [`git config`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) knob for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make a commit to pass everything to lowercase on both branches before merge.

Comment: I can do that for the head of each branch, but for the common ancestor??

Comment: @janou195 Just leave it alone.